# WPF - Set the same style to multiple controls

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary

Is it possible to set the same style to multiple controls?
I was tried the following way. But 1st Button style was not applied correctly, in second style applied fine.

**Design:**

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Foreground="White" Margin="0,0,5,0">1st Button</TextBlock>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource ViewButton}" />
    <TextBlock Foreground="White" Margin="25,0,5,0">2nd Button</TextBlock>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource ViewButton}" />
</StackPanel>
```

**Resource:**

```
<Style x:Key="ViewButton" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="/Images/View.png" Stretch="None" Width="24" Height="24" />
                <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold">View</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2,0,10,0"/>
</Style>
```

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't you use template instead of content in the style?

Comment: @JanneMatikainen Yes, I used Template before, but I have to use ContentTemplate to make it work. Finally nkoniishvt's solution helped me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're setting twice the same Content to two different Controls. The problem is that the StackPanel in the Setter.Value can't have two Parents so the last use will be applied. You can use ContentTemplate to make it work:

```
<Style x:Key="ViewButton" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="/Images/View.png" Stretch="None" Width="24" Height="24" />
                    <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold">View</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2,0,10,0"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks. Before I tried <Setter Property="Template"> instead of <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">. Thanks for pointing to me the right way :)

Answer (score 0):

....
      ....
      ....

You have to mention the TargetType in the as Button. and You need to write the style property following the style name as i wrote.

Hope this will work for You..

thanks

Comment: <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="test">
      ....
      ....
      ....
</Style>

<Button Style="{StaticResource test}" />